# python socket и mikrotik Packet Sniffer stream

Tags: python, mikrotik

Имеется mikrotik на котором запущен пакетный сниффер, который мониторит CDP пакеты и стримит результаты на сервер. На сервере нет wireshark, но есть питон 3.10

Вопрос такой, как мне перехватить стрим данных с микротика питоном?

Answer (score 0):

Микротик шлет в tzsp. Перехватить стрим просто. Пиши обычный UDP сервер и принимай.

На питон есть снифер [scapy](https://scapy.net/) с ним можно писать в pcap или разбирать вплоть до полей CDP